# Is there a pagination option for WPF/Silverlight RichEditControls?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, devexpress

I have a `RichEditControl` with a given width and height. It's usually a one page document, but sometimes documents can get longer than that. When that happens, the `RichEditControl` adds a page to it underneath the current one, and a vertical scroll bar to navigate both.

**Is there a way to make the document show only one page at a time, so I see Page 1 by default until I write enough to get a page jump, and then I only see page 2 in screen?**

This would probably require some sort of pagination, which I imagine is not built-in, so my derived question is:

Since there is no ability to re-size control based on content size ([source](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q257530)), **would it be better to just count the number of pages, and make the RichEditControl height a multiple of that number?** Since this is all inside a bigger `ScrollViewer`, I'm trying to avoid more inner scroll bars.

Comment: You should post this in the DevExpress forum:

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/